# Rotate Image in PushbuttonField does not work

Tags: java, itext

I am using `com.itextpdf.text.Image`. I have 2 image and I want to put it into a specific field of a template pdf.
I have no problem to put image into a pdf, but if image *width* is > than *height* I want to rotate it. I have try this, but it does not work - there is no error, but in the output pdf image is not rotated as expected.

```
Image a = Image.getInstance(front);
if(a.getWidth()>a.getHeight()) {
    a.setRotationDegrees(90); 
    a.setAbsolutePosition(0, 0);
}

PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("C:/Users/Desktop/Template.pdf");  
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/Desktop/out.pdf")); 
AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();

PushbuttonField ad = form.getNewPushbuttonFromField("Front");
ad.setLayout(PushbuttonField.LAYOUT_ICON_ONLY);
ad.setProportionalIcon(true);
ad.setImage(a);
form.replacePushbuttonField("Front", ad.getField());

stamper.setFormFlattening(true);
stamper.close();
reader.close();
```

Comment: In the line `ad1.setImage(b);`, where is `b`coming from?

Comment: You should remove all the code that does not matter from the example, it will make understanding your problem easier.

Comment: I don't think so, I have also try to rotate the PushbuttonField field of the first image of my template, doing so the first Image was effectively rotate but the field too, and It change also the position of my second image.

Comment: @LizLamperouge are we try to solve your Image rotation issue, or your unsuccessful PushbuttonField rotation? If image, then please do what *javahippie* asks for.

Comment: I don't want to rotate the PushbuttonField but the image that I want to put on it, I have tried to rotate PushbuttonField only for a test.

Comment: It is so difficult to understand my question? I have in input 2 image, I want to rotate the first one only if the width is > than height  and then put the Image in the PushbuttonField.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strangely, but

```
img.setRotationDegrees(90);
pushbuttonField.setImage(img);
```

does not rotate image within `PushbuttonField`. So I did it with `PdfTemplate`.

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("D://testPdf.pdf");
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream("D://stamperPdf.pdf"));
AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();

// get Image and rotate it
Image img = Image.getInstance("D://testImg.png");
img.setRotationDegrees(90);
img.setAbsolutePosition(0, 0);

// create template with scaled width and height
PdfTemplate tp = PdfTemplate.createTemplate(stamper.getWriter(), img.getScaledWidth(),
                                            img.getScaledHeight());
tp.addImage(img);


PushbuttonField field = form.getNewPushbuttonFromField("Field");
field.setLayout(PushbuttonField.LAYOUT_ICON_ONLY);
field.setProportionalIcon(true);
field.setTemplate(tp);  // set template with image to field
form.replacePushbuttonField("Field", field.getField());
```

As output - rotated image scaled proportionally in `PushbuttonField`.